# Is there such a thing as too many include paths?

Tags: c++, c++11

In an attempt to organize my code base I have been moving my files into a  hierarchy of folders
e.g.:

> - Folder A
>
>   - Folder AA
>
>     - Foo.cpp
>     - Foo.hpp
> - Folder B
> - Folder C
>
>   - Folder CA
>
>     - Bar.cpp
>     - Bar.hpp
> - Folder D
> - Folder E

While it has made finding individual files easier, it has made referencing them more difficult. For Bar.cpp to reference Foo.hpp I have to put a relative path to the header file:

```
#include "../../Folder A/Folder AA/Foo.hpp"
```

Initially I did this every time I needed to reference a file but it not only looks rather ugly it is also really fragile. Anytime I decide to reorganize files it would break every reference to that file.

To fix this, I'm considering adding an include path (-I) so that the above include statement would be reduced to:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
```

Is there going to be a significant performance hit on compiling if I add include paths for every folder in my folder hierarchy (I have around 9)? Is this a good practice at all? What do people in industry do in this situation?

Comment: Just, in the `#include` directives use paths relative to a common single include directory, e.g. for g++ you might have `cpath=c:\somewhere\reuse\include`. I place symbolic links there (in Windows junctions via `mklink /j`) to the various libraries, e.g. Boost. This avoids having all the libraries physically placed under the include directory.

Comment: I'd stick with manually specifying the relative path. Verbose yes, but it solves problems such as having different headers with the same name in different folders/namespaces. If you relocate all the headers to a common folder, you'll have all sort of problems down the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any single way of solving for this, however the betst working solutions I have seen are;

1. Yours. As you describe, simply leave the header file with the source code, and have the Makefile have all the directories listed in a `-I` option -- there is not really any noticeable performance issue with compiling. The issue is with Maintaining the list in the makefile but that can be automated with some macros if that is needed.
2. Keep the `.h` file with the source code and symlink all `.h` file to a `/include` directory in your project.  You can automated the symlink as an initial step of your Makefile so that you don't have to keep that up-to-date.

In either case project convention is important, so if your project does not have to integrate with anything you are free to do what you want, but if you are making a package for some other system, you should follow whatever convention they have already set out.

Comment: I'm going to try the symlink solution. It seems like the cleanest out of everything I've heard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that common practice dictates that you include the root folder on your include paths. That way you can use paths relatively to root:

```
#include "Folder A/Folder AA/Foo.hpp"
```

This is given that the root folder is where "Folder A" is located. I think that should solve it, but for the sake of completeness, I might add that additional folders to your search path might increase complexity when the compiler is looking for the files, as  it has to look in more folders when doing so. However, the performance hit is so absolutely marginal that probably not even a profiler would reflect it. Notice that any modern computer can look into 9 folders for a file in a "nano-blink of an eye".

I might just add an extra recommendation: don't overwork your file structure. Unless your project is to grow to many hundreds or thousands of files you might not need to. And if it does, you better consider breaking it into smaller modules.

Comment: Does not really solve the problem of it being fragile when restructuring the code.

Comment: It doesn't. But the recommendation is not to do it, unless the project is big. And if it is, than it should be broken into modules, which does solve the problem. This is C, if you change the file structure you need to change the includes. I don't think it's a good idea to just include all folders with `-I`, think about setting the project up on a different environment. Painful.

Answer (score 0):

If both Foo.cpp and Bar.cpp both need to include Foo.hpp, then you'd put Foo.hpp into a common include folder, and then you'd have your Makefile have that folder in the include path.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all header files in a single directory. Make sure your header files have header guards, so you can save your time instead struggling over cyclic reference or other related issues. And create a makefile to manage your build process. While using  make utility by using option `-I` you can specify your include path.